# How to load imagelist with system dialog icons

Tags: delphi, winapi, icons, standard-icons

How to load a `TCustomImageList` with all system icons used by Windows in dialog boxes (Standard icons like warning, error, information, confirmation..)?

[image]

I would like to find a solution which works on Windows XP and later.

Comment: NB: This is tricky stuff, depending on what you want to do with the image list. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285890/how-to-load-a-small-system-icon/4286601, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613513/compliant-loading-of-small-oem-icon-with-loadimage

Comment: See also http://www.catch22.net/tuts/system-image-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`LoadImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`LoadIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Quick example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t_Icon: TIcon;

begin
  t_Icon := TIcon.Create();
  t_Icon.Handle := LoadImage( 0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(32513), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE or LR_SHARED );

  if ( t_Icon.Handle <> 0 ) then
    ImageList1.AddIcon( t_Icon );

// .............

  t_Icon.Free();
end;
```

Comment: I would use `IDI_ERROR` instead of `MAKEINTRESOURCE(32513)`

Comment: Then (in case of LoadImage) it's better to define OIC_... constants, IMHO.