# Getting modern system icons with LoadIcon

Tags: c, windows, winapi, icons

I'm using [`LoadIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadicona) for loading system icons such as the "Attention" sign. This works fine, but this gives me the icon with the old (I think) Windows 7 look.

My program runs on Windows 10.

**Code:**

```
hicon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_EXCLAMATION);
```

[image]

Is there a way to get the icons with the new look?

On the other hand [`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) with the `MB_ICONEXCLAMATION` flag shows the new icon.

Comment: Have you tried with LoadImage(..., IMAGE_ICON, ...)?

Comment: @SimonMourier no, and I wouldn't know how.

Comment: How do you learn anything? You read the documentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've read the documentation of `LoadImage`, but maybe I didn't understand everything. Is it about OEM images?

Comment: look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826050/how-to-load-a-timage-using-task-dialog-common-icons the MessageBox actually load icon from *imageres.dll* with `0x54` id

Comment: @RbMm thanks, that's somewhat helpful. But loading from imageres.dll is maybe not the best option, because it's an implementation detail, e.g. would this work on Windows 7?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan when I commented "no, and I wouldn't know how", it wasn't about how to use `LoadImage` but it about how using `LoadImage` to that the modern icons show.

Comment: @SimonMourier It doesn't help, I get the old fashioned icons with `LoadImage`.

Comment: ok - [`LoadIconWithScaleDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-loadiconwithscaledown)`(0, IDI_EXCLAMATION, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON), &hi);` do task

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I saw that `MessageBoxW` uses the [`LoadIconWithScaleDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-loadiconwithscaledown) function for loading icons instead of `LoadImage` or `LoadIcon`. With standard icon IDs (from 0x7f00 (`IDI_APPLICATION..IDI_SHIELD`) this function actually loads images from *imageres.dll* (while `LoadImage` loads them from *user32.dll*).

Comment: Fastest, upvote +accept!! I just figured out how to do it with `LoadIconWithScaleDown`! Thanks!

Comment: @Jabberwocky - https://i.imgur.com/6GxdfFK.png this is how `LoadIconWithScaleDown` redirect standard icons to *imageres.dll* - `IDI_EXCLAMATION` - 0x7F03 is redirected to 0x54 from *imageres.dll*. strange that `LoadImage` not do the same and this not documented