# How can I display the IDI_INFORMATION icon at 16 x 16 in the lower left of my dialog?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, icons

When you use a `CTaskDialog` you can set the footer icon, which is 16 x 16. I would like to do something similar on my own dialog:

[image]

At the moment my own dialog has a static resource at the bottom.

---

I know that I can load the information icon like this:

```
HICON hInfo = LoadStandardIcon(IDI_INFORMATION);
```

1. How do we load it as 16 x 16?
2. How do we display it on the left on the dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you (hopefully) don't need to support Windows XP, you can use [`LoadIconWithScaleDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-loadiconwithscaledown)

For example:

```
HICON hicon;
HRESULT hr = LoadIconWithScaleDown(NULL, (PCWSTR)IDI_INFORMATION,
             GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON) / 2, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON) / 2,  &hicon);
...
```

This gives you the additional benefit of loading the modern version of the icons instead of the old ugly ones. See also [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60887975/getting-modern-system-icons-with-loadicon).

Comment: Awesome. And you would use that with a CStatic control dialog resource. Correct?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle just use it  the same way as if you'd use `LoadStandardIcon`. Simply `yourstaticcontrol.SetIcon(hicon)`.

Comment: Is it better to use GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON) etc instead of 16 to factor for DPI awareness?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, actually `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON) / 2` for the 16x16 icon.

Comment: `GetSystemMetrics` returns logical pixels. It is not DPI-aware, and indeed cannot be (which value should it return if you have two displays with different DPI settings?). If your application is marked as (per-monitor) DPI-aware you have to manually scale those sizes by a factor calculated from the result of calling e.g. [`GetDpiForWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdpiforwindow).

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for pointing that out. But for a system DPI aware program (not per monitor), it doesn't matter. Also `GetDpiForWindow` is only available on Windows 10, which leads to further complications if older Windows versions need to be supported (using `GetProcaddress` and fall back to `GetSystemMetrics` if appropriate).

Comment: I have used the picture control and mapped it to an icon. I added the code and it loads and displays. But its placement is somewhat ugley - upper left of the static control. Can we centralize it?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I think you should ask a new question with more details.

Comment: [`GetDpiForMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getdpiformonitor) is available on all supported versions of Windows. You can get the monitor with a call to [`MonitorFromWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow). As for *"system DPI aware"* I'm struggling to find an explanation why that isn't called *"DPI unaware"*.

Comment: @and [`SS_CENTERIMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-control-styles).

Comment: @IInspectable Great! - Now spotted that at the very bottom in the IDE. Sorted!

Comment: You should use `[GetSystemMetrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics)(SM_CXSMICON)` and `SM_CYSMICON` to retrieve the size of the small icon. You can use [`GetSystemMetricsForDpi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetricsfordpi) to get DPI-aware sizes.

Comment: @IInspectable *As for "system DPI aware" I'm struggling to find an explanation why that isn't called "DPI unaware".* These are two different levels of DPI awareness. **DPI Unaware** app always runs as if the DPI is 96 (scale 100%), and the system scales up the window . A **System DPI aware** app can scale itself up to the *system DPI*, the DPI of the main monitor when the user logged in to the system. If the current DPI of a monitor matches that (system) DPI, the window renders sharply; in all other cases, the system will scale the app up or down to match the current DPI of the monitor.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I understand the semantics, but the situation with system DPI awareness hasn't improved over DPI unawareness: Window contents are crisp on the primary display and may not be on others. System DPI awareness was a half-baked solution that no one should be using.

Comment: @IInspectable System DPI Awareness was the only option available until Windows 8.1. New apps should implement Per-Monitor (v2) DPI Awareness.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by using `Picture Control`, and position it whenever you want. And as code you could do:

```
CStatic  myicon;
myicon.Attach(GetDlgItem(ID_STATIC_ICON));
myicon.SetIcon(static_cast<HICON>(::LoadImage(nullptr, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0)));
```

I didn't test the code, but should work.

[image]